# Python: list files every 30sec and avoid processing duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help me with challenge i have, that is to list files every 30seconds and process them (process them means for example -- copying to another location, each file is moved out of the directory once processed), and when i list files after 30seconds, i want to avoid any files that are listed previously for processing (due to the reason that they were listed previously and FOR LOOP is still in progress)

Means i want to avoid duplicate file processing while listing the files every 30seconds.

here is my code.

```
def List_files():
   path = 'c:\\projects\\hc2\\'
   files = []
   for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
       for file in f:
           if '.txt' in file:
               files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

class MyFilethreads:
    def __init__(self, t1):
        self.t1 = t1

    def start_threading(self):
        for file in List_files():
             self.t1 = Thread(target=<FILEPROCESS_FUNCTION>, args=(file,))
             self.t1.start()

t1 = Thread()
myclass = MyFilethreads(t1)

while True:
    myclass.start_threading()
    time.sleep(30)
```

I have not included my actual function for processing files, since its big,,it is called with thread as `FILEPROCESS_FUNCTION`.

`Problem:`

if the file size is high, my file processing time may increase some times (in other words, FOR LOOP is taking more than 30 sec ) but i cant reduce 30sec timer since it's very rare possibility, and my python script takes hundreds of files every min..

Hence, i am looking for a way to avoid files that are already listed previously, and by this i wanted to avoid duplicate file processing.

please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an idea: with the [watchdog module](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) you can monitor files or folder for a changes in real-time.

Comment: Hi,, thanks for response.. i had a look, and its helpful.. i had resolved this issue by using thread join() method.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary in your class, and insert all the files you have seen. then, in your `start_threading` check if the file is in the dictionary, and `pass` in that case.

Comment: thanks a lot.. join() method in threading helped me.